# How to pass custom props in react-select?

Tags: typescript, react-select

How can i pass custom props in react-select without ts ignore? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u30iL.png)
Cause i always need to put ingore where i use custom prop [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3moz8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (or at least should not), as this requires changing react-select typescript definition files.

You might be able to override the typing definition locally, but keep in mind there is already an [open issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/5274) about this matter.